# Firebase dynamic links not working for Firebase sign in with email link (password less)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase `sendSignInWithEmailLink` with the url generated as part of the Firebase dynamic link.

1. The firebase dynamic url looks like:
   e.g: https://myapp.page.link/H1c4
2. The url from step 1 is sent as part of `sendSignInWithEmailLink`
3. User received email and clicks on the verification link.
4. At the end of redirection I can see that the url contains the oobCode as shown below:

https://myapp.page.link/H1c4?apiKey=&oobCode=YG2N2eLU4qGBsDeLU5cVsDrzF9qwkGzoUepInuA9pm0AAAFtfk41Nw&mode=signIn&lang=en

5. When my app receives the dynamic link finally, it is loosing the oobCode. My app gets

https://myapp.page.link/uEOBUnv1k4XclzwfsT5NXnGBgAA3/
The part after link/ is a custom data which I used while generating the link in step 1.

When I use `isSignInWithEmailLink` for validating the link in step 5, I get the result as FALSE indicating it's not a valid email link.

But if I provide the full URL from step 4 in the code(manually), the `isSignInWithEmailLink` returns TRUE.

I think I've done all required but Firebase dynamic link is not persisting the oobCode as part of the link sent to the app on the device.

Has anyone seen this and know what could be the problem? keen to get feedback here before reporting as an issue in Github.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom dynamic link with a path, eg. https://myapp.page.link/H1c4? If so, that is currently not supported with Firebase Auth. Only custom domains with no paths are supported, eg. https://myapp.page.link.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'm using Firebase dynamic link and while generating the url from the code it always adds the path. I can't generate a dynamic link without the path. If I just use the base url e.g. https://myapp.page.link without any path, when Firebase auth redirects in the browser, my app is not opening.

It looks like a chicken and egg problem unless there is a way for me to use the Firebase dynamic link without a path to open my app.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, looking at it, is it the problem with Firebase auth or the Firebase dynamic link?
Because the last leg is a GET request to dynamic link url:

GET https://myapp.page.link/tpdZ?apiKey=&oobCode=eVD1zYnR1bvYGie8kgkpKbkOswiEk3tJ0p6vMagGLOoAAAFtg6bG0g&mode=signIn&lang=en

Response is:
https://myapp.page.link

Is it Firebase auth loosing the context or the Firebase dynamic link unable to retain the additional query strings?

Any help, much appreciated. 

Thanks